# $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}U(t)f=f$ implies the convergence at each point?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I am new here and I would like to see if you can help me.
My question is if the limit $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow 0}U(t)f=f$ imply the convergence at each point?

It seems to me that the statement is true, but I don't know how to write it. Can you please give me some help?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange, please add further details to your question, like what are $U$ or $f$ and what do you mean by convergence at each point.

Comment: Sorry, I had to clarify what I'm talking about. $U$ refers to unitary operators that are strongly continuous. To clarify better, I'm reading about Stone's theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_theorem_on_one-parameter_unitary_groups